# Как правильно вызывать активити?

Tags: android

Есть активити, которая заточена под загрузку данных с URL и вывод их списком. 
Есть 3 кнопки, в зависимости от кнопки формируется свой URL, откуда нужно будет скачать данные.

Как сделать так, чтобы использовалась одна и та же активити?

Понятное дело, что нужно использовать `Intent`, вот только как сделать так, чтобы данные шли в разные окна, а не в одно?

Comment: вызвать с разных окон :)
Не дублируйте вопросы, конкретизируйте вопрос в одном месте

Comment: а пример можно, просто не до конца понимаю ,что значит "с разных окон"

Comment: >чтобы данные шли в разные окна, а не в одно?

это ответ на ваш вопрос, что вы имели ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понимаю, то в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, вы хотите послать во вторую активити разный URL? Вам подойдет метод **setData(Uri data)** у объекта **Intent**.
Есть отличный урок на эту тему вот [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/70-urok-31-zachem-u-intent-est-atribut-data-chto-takoe-uri-vyzyvaem-sistemnye-prilozhenija.html)

Comment: Хотя перечитал еще и раз) и понял, что ничего я не понял)))
Вы хотите что бы у вас создавался отдельный экземпляр одного и того же Активити в зависимости от нажатой кнопки? или что значит "данные шли в разные окна" если у вас 1 активити для обработки

Answer (score -1):

Вот припустим у тебя есть Activity в котором ты обрабатывеш свои запросы, и есть три кнопки , при нажатии на каждую ты хочеш создать новое активити.

```
public class MainActivity {

btnActOne;
btnActTwo;
btnActThree;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create buttons
btnActOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActOne);
btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
btnActThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActThree);
     btnActOne.setOnClickListener(this);
     btnActTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
     btnActThree.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Обработчик кнопки:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btnActOne:
  // TODO Call second activity

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
  startActivity(intent);

  break;
default:
  break;
}
}
```

Создаеш еще один клас Activity

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Кнопки есть, обработчик нажатия описан. Просто создаешь столько класов Activity, сколько нужно, в даном случае описан простое создание и переход на второе Activity.